# How to use Cloudflare between client and AWS Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare

I am try to use Cloudflare between client and AWS route 53. This is process.

Step 1: Route 53 use A records with EC2 instance IP address.
Step 2: Use route nameserver records to configure NS records in Cloudflare DNS records.
Step 3: Then Cloudflare nameserver records use to configure Domain provider records.

I using this method to get Cloudflare features like web application firewall (WAF), SSL, cache, CDN etc.

Is this method work and what are cons for this method?

Comment: Route53 and Cloudflare are both DNS services. You can't use them both at the same time on the same domain name.